# How to continue the background of a div on another div/span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

In my webpage I have have a block with an background and below I have a button that should continue the background.

Here is an example. The left image is what my webpage is now, and the right image is what the webpage should be. You can see that the background continues on the button.

[image: Example image of my problem.]

My code structure is something like:

```
<div id="section-1">
  <div class="shown-content">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="content">
      ... here are shown contents ...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden-content">
    ... here are hidden contents ...
  </div>

  <div class="button-content">
    <span class="button">FOLD OUT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The functionality is that when you click on the button, it triggers the JQuery [`slideToggle`](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and it shows/hides the `hidden-content` div.

My idea is to set the button background the same width and height than the content background and then position it where appropriate. But I'm a bit lost because I don't find any way of doing this, and maybe you know a better way.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net so we can see what is wrong. :)

Comment: jycr: There's a BIG IMAGE showing what is wrong! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your placeholder for the image is 100px in height and the button is 30px.

Let's say your button always are in the center of the main image div.

Then you need an image that is 130px high, where the background position is set to center top and the buttons background position is set to center bottom.

Sample

```
.imgdiv {
    background-position: center top
}

.buttdiv {
    background-position: center bottom
}
```

If your button isn't in the center you need to adjust the "center" part of background position to make it match the main image

Comment: I have to adjust the position and also the background size of the button, with JavaScript. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial idea is probably the best solution.

Use background position to correctly position you div.

```
.button-content{
    background: url('') no-repeat 200 100%;
}
```

Numbers afer no-repeat are **X** position **Y** position of background image.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution, hope it will help you.

Place the fold out button absolute in the relative positioned `#section-1`.
While placing it absolute, it will only take the width it needs. Then we use the pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after` to fill the space on the left and the right with the background color of the body (in my example white).

The  HTML looks like this (expandable with your rest code):

```
<div id="section-1">
    <div class="hidden-content">
        hidden content
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        Fold out
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#section-1 {
    min-height: 100px; /*use min-height so it will expand */
    background: url('pic.jpg');
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 30px; /* height of .button */
    overflow: hidden; /* to hide the :before and :after */
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
.button:before, .button:after {
    content: ' ';
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    left: -1000px;
    height: 30px;
}
.button:after {
    left: 100%;
}
.hidden-content {
    display: none;
}
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6Qm5/).